# Scroll lag after external display connect

Tags: display, macos

After connecting or disconnecting external display some lag appears on every scroll in every app. Only restart helps (or windowserver restart).

This problem was on Mavericks and still on Yosemite. It was problem on mba 2013 and also on mba 2014.

This bug only affects scrolling, but this is driving me crazy, because I often connect external displays on work.